# How do I iterate pictures implemented as columns in a div in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an album of pictures.

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <figure class="figure">
    <img src="..." class="figure-img img-fluid gallery-item">
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">...</figcaption>
  </figure>
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery {
  column-width: 300px;
  column-gap: 0;
}

.gallery-item {
  width: 350px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}
```

The number of pictures is not fixed, and their heights can be different.

I am trying to iterate figures in JQuery this way:

```
var items = $('.gallery').children();
```

In this case the order of iterated pictures is vertical. I mean first I get the pictures from the first column from up to down, after that full second column, etc. I understand this is because the order of figures in my HTML is supposed to be vertical. But I need a way to iterate the figures this way:

[image]

Probably, there is a way to do it with JQuery only. Or maybe I should make some changes in my HTML and CSS. What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you need to iterate them in this particular order?

Comment: I want to keep the intuitive order of pictures in popup.

Comment: Check bootstrap, it will help you with column layout

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort the items before iterating (pure js solution):

```js
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.gallery figure')]

items.sort((a, b) => a.offsetTop/2 - b.offsetTop);

var output = ''

for ({textContent:t} of items) output += `${t} `

console.log(output)
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 400px; width:500px;
}

figure {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <figure style="height:100px">1</figure>
  <figure style="height:80px">2</figure>
  <figure style="height:120px">3</figure>
  <figure style="height:70px">4</figure>
  <figure style="height:100px">5</figure>
  <figure style="height:100px">6</figure>
  <figure style="height:80px">7</figure>
  <figure style="height:120px">8</figure>
  <figure style="height:70px">9</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the number of columns fixed?  If you will always have 3 columns, you can label each column with a class:

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
<figure class="figure col1">
    <img src="..." class="figure-img img-fluid gallery-item">
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">...</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="figure col2">
    <img src="..." class="figure-img img-fluid gallery-item">
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">...</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="figure col3">
    <img src="..." class="figure-img img-fluid gallery-item">
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">...</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="figure col1">
    <img src="..." class="figure-img img-fluid gallery-item">
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">...</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="figure col2">
    <img src="..." class="figure-img img-fluid gallery-item">
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">...</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="figure col3">
    <img src="..." class="figure-img img-fluid gallery-item">
    <figcaption class="figure-caption">...</figcaption>
</figure>
...
```

Jquery:

```
var items = [];

for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    $(".col"+i).each(function () {
        items.push($(this));
    });
}
```